# Apache Wicket: Display an error message when StalePageException occurs

Tags: java, exception, wicket, wicket-6

I have a Java application using the Apache Wicket 6.x; sometimes exception [StalePageException](https://ci.apache.org/projects/wicket/apidocs/6.x/org/apache/wicket/core/request/mapper/StalePageException.html) is triggered as described below and shows up in the log. However, because there is no feedback to the user, the application behaves unexpectedly causing frustration.

How can I capture the [StalePageException](https://github.com/apache/wicket/blob/master/wicket-core/src/main/java/org/apache/wicket/core/request/mapper/StalePageException.java) and present a message to the user (preferably using a feedback panel) explaining the situation?

> Open a stateful page in a tab/window, then copy the url from the
>   address bar and open it in a new tab/window. Then go back to the first
>   tab/window and try to click on any stateful link. This will lead to
>   StalePageException.
>
> It is thrown because Wicket detects that the same page instance has
>   been rendered between the render of the current page and the click on
>   the link. Wicket does this because it is not sure whether there are
>   any changes in the page tree hierarchy between the initial rendering
>   and the click event. It is even possible that this link is no more
>   existing in the last version of the page, so this click could lead to
>   ComponentNotFoundException if StalePageException is not thrown
>   earlier.
>
> StalePageException just leads to render of the current page. So the
>   user will see the last version of the page and (s)he will need to
>   click the link again.

Answer (score 2):

You need to use custom IRequestCycleListener (extend from AbstractRequestCycleListener).
Override #onException() and if the passed exception is StalePageException then you may use Session.get().error("...") to report that to the user. Just make sure you have a FeedbackPanel in the current page.

Answer (score 0):

Would you wanna try a rather simpler approach by capturing the exception instance (lets say `e`). Then check for the type of this excception. And eventually use one of the inherited methods from `java.lang.Throwable` to capture the details

```
if(e instanceof StalePageException ){
       e.printStackTrace(); //can use other methods as per desire : getCause, getLocalizedMessage, getMessage, getStackTrace, initCause, printStackTrace
}
```

Please verify if getting the exception instance is possible for you to highlight in your code.